# Get All Username from OpenFire with XMPP

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xmpp, openfire

In my application I need to get **All the UserName** from **OpenFire**.

i used below code but it doesn't give nil data.

and i thing something is wrong in my **didReceiveIQ** method but using first time XMPP so don't get the actual problem.

my code for getting data is

```
- (void)getAllRegisteredUsers {

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>"
                                                        error:&error];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get"
                             to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Domain Name with jid"]]
                      elementID:[xmppStream generateUUID] child:query];
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}
```

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];

NSLog(@"queryelement %@",queryElement);

if (queryElement) {

    NSLog(@"query in if");
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

        NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [mArray addObject:jid];

        NSLog(@"User in OpenFire = %@",jid);

    }

    NSLog(@"mArray = %@",mArray);

}

return NO;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated....

Comment: can you tell me which XEP Extension have this stanza, through which you are trying to get all register user.

Comment: i included most it in my application from github and dont know much about it. but which one is required most for it as you know that tell me then i'll tell you that one is included or not. but i am getting **mArray** nil.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on getting all registered users from openfire into my app. I tried all the above methods but non helped me!
After trying a lot i got a solution for getting all the registered users...
here's the code :

```
- (void)getAllRegisteredUsers {

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>" error:&error];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"none" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"both" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}

- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq{

    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];

    if (queryElement) {
        NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
        NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

            NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
            [mArray addObject:jid];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",mArray);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This worked for me, hope it will work for others as well... :)

Comment: hey what is ANY_ID_NAME what  thing i have to specify here. and why yo add attribute name

Comment: @MadBurea ANY_ID_NAME is part of xml syntax. We have to pass it as it is. We add attribute to specify which type of users we want to fetch from rooster. Here i have specified none and both type of users.

Comment: XMPPIQ *iq = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
This throw error in swift 3 as You cannot convert  XMPPIQ  to DDXMLElement.

Comment: @MadBurea are you using this "XMPPIQ *iq = [DDXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];" syntax in swift?

Comment: No man How can i use that. it's var iq: XMPPIQ? = DDXMLElement(name: "iq")

Comment: @MadBurea

let iq: DDXMLElement = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("iq") as! DDXMLElement
    iq.addAttributeWithName("type", stringValue: "get")
    iq.addAttributeWithName("none", stringValue: "ANY_ID_NAME")
   iq.addAttributeWithName("both", stringValue: "ANY_ID_NAME")

    let query: DDXMLElement = DDXMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "jabber:iq:roster") as! DDXMLElement
    iq.addChild(query)

    xmppStream?.sendElement(iq)

Answer (score 0):

Through this code you can get the roster list (Your friend list from openr fire server).

```
   NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];

   NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
   [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
   [iq addChild:query];
   [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

And response will be same what you expecting.

Comment: Thanks for answer but how to fetch Username from it ? may be the question is dumb but i am new so don't get username after printing it. can you please help me in this ?

Comment: What the response you are getting from OpenFire?

Comment: at the end sendElement done so where i shall get the response ? means my question to you is, is there any method to get response of your code ? if so then how ?

Comment: In `didReceiveIQ` method, while you are sending iq request then surely reponse will respond to iq only.

Comment: I am getting this in **didReceiveIQ** method **<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" to="current_logged_username@servername"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>**. So, from this also not getting the all users list.

Comment: I told it will give the list of users which are in your roster. Means your friend list only.

Comment: I'm getting null for queryElement in Response

Comment: Hello, I have got the result in the iq but how to convert this iq in to nsxmlelement or in array? is there any function for same?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue() ] ;
[xmppRoster fetchRoster ] ;
```

And you should init the `XMPPRoster` before fetch roster:

```
    xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
//  xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];

xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];
```

After you send `fetchRoster` on `XMPPRoster` object , you can get all the username from 
`XMPPRosterDelegate`'s  method:

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceiveRosterItem:(NSXMLElement *)item
```

Hope this can help :]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I got queryElement as nil as well. I've changed the response code to see the XML like this:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName:@"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
    NSLog(@"IQ: %@",iq);
    if (queryElement) {

        NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
        NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

            NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
            NSLog(@"%@",jid);
            [mArray addObject:jid];
        }
    }
    return NO; 
}
```